# PHP Concatenate file output to string

Tags: php, include

I am rewriting a piece of a program to change it from using "echos" throughout the script to create a large output variable using Heredocs instead, which outputs at the end of the file.

A piece of the script includes another PHP file that directly outputs HTML and has php logic within the HTML it outputs.  This file is used by other pieces of the overall program that are not yet being rewritten (due to time constraints).

Is it possible to append the output of another file to an $output variable?  I've tried doing this, but it it doesn't work for string appending:

```
$output .= include 'foo.php';

$output .= file_get_contents('foo.php');
```

The file_get_contents wrote all the PHP logic directly in HTML, as I suspected it would and the straight 'include' echo'd the HTML as I also expected.

Is there a method to get the output buffer of the file and append to a string?

EDIT: Nevermind the question, I completely forgot about OB_Buffering.  Added an answer with my solution, no need to answer this one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel stupid.  I found the answer 5 minutes after posting, I completely forgot about ob_buffering:

```
ob_start();
include('./foo.php');
$output .= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```